# text showing in the text box when testing in flash but not showing when uploaded to the sever

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a dynamic text field, the text is saved in a folder assets when i test the in flash the movie works fine text shows in the box scroll bar works but when i uploaded to the server onto the joomla site it shows everything except no text the scroll bar works everything bar the text shows.

my path am using in joomla is images/story/storybook.swf

i have put the assets folder with the text files inside of the story folder

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, textLoaded);

textLoader.load(new URLRequest("assets/story_02.txt"));


function textLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    info_txt.text = textLoader.data;
    info_txt.wordWrap = true;
}



function upScrollText(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    //trace (info_txt.scrollV -=1);
    info_txt.scrollV -=1;
}
bScrollUp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,upScrollText);

function downScrollText(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    //trace (info_txt.scrollV +=1);
    info_txt.scrollV +=1;
}
bScrollDown.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, downScrollText);

var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(bScrollDrag.x,bScrollDrag.y,0,100);
var dragging:Boolean = false;
function dragScroll(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    bScrollDrag.startDrag(false,bounds);
    dragging = true;
}
function dropScroll(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    bScrollDrag.stopDrag();
    dragging = false;
}
bScrollDrag.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragScroll);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropScroll);

function checkSlider(evt:Event):void
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        //trace("scroll");
        info_txt.scrollV = Math.round((bScrollDrag.y - bounds.y)*info_txt.maxScrollV/100)
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkSlider);

function speechScrolled(evt:Event):void
{
    bScrollDrag.y = bounds.y+(info_txt.scrollV*100/info_txt.maxScrollV)
}

info_txt.addEventListener(Event.SCROLL,speechScrolled); 

info_txt.mouseWheelEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: "/images...

```
new URLRequest("/images/story/assets/story_02.txt")
```

then change: `info_txt.text = textLoader.data;`

by : `info_txt.text = evt.data;`

Comment: @percy are you using htaccess in your joomla website

Comment: @percy if you paste /images/story/assets/story_02.txt in browser adressbar do you get txt file or not

Comment: Thanks mgraph i pasted into the url and the text does appear in the browser

Comment: I have renamed the thaccess.txt to .htaccess

Comment: I used classic text and not TLF also it is is a dynamic text field i have tried putting the swf file and the just in the image folderbut still no text